# Python pandas : when to use pd.(function name), and when to use (name of dataframe).function

Tags: python, pandas

I'm practicing the use of python pandas and I have a question as follows:

Sometimes when I call a function, I call it by a format like (name of dataframe).(function name), such as :

```
df.groupby()
```

However there're a few functions which the above format doesn't seem to work. Instead, I have to write it as pandas.(function name). For example:

```
pd.to_numeric()
```

Can anyone tell me if there's any rule of thumbs on determining when to use the first format & when to use the second format ?

Thanks.
Owen

Comment: There is no rule. Read documentation.

Answer (score 1):

In the [documents](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/genindex.html#T) you can see a list of all functions and in parathesis next to that function it tells you where it is located.

For example:

[to_numeric](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html#pandas-to-numeric) (in module pandas) 
  use pd.to_numeric

However, [to_json](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html#pandas-dataframe-to-json)(pandas.DataFrame method)
  use df.to_json

Answer (score 0):

If df.function fails try pd.function(df).
If that fails, read the documentation. Some pd functions transform Series and Dataframe types (like pd.to_datetime). Some pandas functions (many, really) fall under the pandas.DataFrame object... Theoretically, you could just open up the code and look for yourself.